# TurtleBeach PX5 - is it possible to use it wired? How bad is it to recharge?

Tags: audio, headphones, wireless-headset

I am thinking about buying a TurtleBeach PX5, and so far everything speaks for it.

What I was not able to find out were two things:

Can I use the XBox-Connector to directly plug-in some audio-device (like an MP3-Player)? If so, would this still require batteries? So basically - can I use this Headset in a wired-mode?

Is it easy to exchange the batteries? Can they be re-charged by plugging in USB or even better, by putting them on a wireless re-charge-plate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The batteries can be charged on their own using a battery charger if you use recharable batteries.  They are very easy to replace.  The headset is wireless thus requires batteries no matter how they are used.

Comment: Do you have this headset? Your answer is not quite the news for me, except maybe that the batteries are easy to replace. And just because it is wireless, might not mean it must use batteries to work - Phillips SHB 9100 e.g. can be used wired without batteries & wireless.

Comment: @Jook - I have the headset by TurtleBeach which offered Stero Wireless Audio and wired communication over XBOX Live Voice ( i.e. wire cord to the controller ).  Otherwise I have the exact same headset.  Just looking at the box contents would prove there is no way to have a wired powered connection with this headset.

Comment: hm, ok, i'll take your word on that, thanks. I am just still clueless about this Xbox-Controller-Jack - is it just for an xbox controller or could you hook up a mp3-player to it too?

Comment: @Jook - It is design just for an Xbox 360 controller.  They sell a version of the headset which offers "wireless chat" all that does is places communicator adapter( bluetooth I believe ) on the controller.

Comment: yeah - just found a hint here - http://www.turtlebeach.com/support/entry/830516941/ - they would have mentioned another possibility.

Comment: @Jook - I thought `back of the mind type deal` you could do bluetooth music playing but I wasn't sure.  I figured the support articles would answer that question ( didn't even address it on puprose ).